# How to choose Android support library Revision?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am upgrading my Android app from android-4.4.2 to android-5.1.1. I am not sure what revision of Android Support libraries I need. For example:

Can I use appcompat-v7(22.3) or since i am compiling my app against 5.1.1, i need matching version of appcompat-v7 e.g. 22.2.1?

This is very confusing to me, explanation would help.

Comment: Use the latest support libraries (currently v23.2.0) and compile with api 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

I would recommend taking the most recent version of the support library.  You want to base your decision off of two things:

Desired Features, Minimum Supported Android version.

Typically you can choose the most recent version and be fine, but if you have specific, and limited, set of features required you may want to pick more carefully.

Also have a look at:

[Support library version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471668/support-library-version)

CommonsWare provides a nice breakdown of some common issues you may encounter, as well as explaining some of the reasons you would encounter them.

Comment: I would want to use latest appcompat but it would not compile because it has values-v23 (i am assuming this is for Android 6.0). Should i just delete this folder and use the library? Deleting it makes it work btw

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084607/android-studio-appcompat-build-fail-values-v23-styles-bases-xml